# Views/Pages is inherited from System.Web.WebPages instead of System.Web.Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

It seems all views/pages in the project is persistently getting inherited from the namespace `System.Web.WebPages` instead of `System.Web.Mvc`.

**_ViewStart.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Here `Layout` refers to `System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase`, where I would expect it to be `System.Web.Mvc.ViewStartPage`.

I have no clue as to why the views are inherited from `System.Web.WebPages.WebPage` instead of `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`. In the config the `pageBaseType` is set to `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` and yet they remain inherited from `System.Web.WebPages.WebPage`.

Below I have included the configuration `web.config`, the packages installed `packages.config` and the project's references `FlexyBox.MVC.Fitness.csproj`.

It should be noted the problems occurred after upgrading to Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015.

Unfortunately I need to support Windows XP so an upgrade to a newer version of MVC is not possible :-(

I hope someone is able to decipher what is going on.

Thanks in advance.

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="facebookSettings" type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection" />
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Utils" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpellChecker" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.XtraCharts" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.XtraCharts.Web" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.XtraReports" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.XtraReports.Web" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="NewRelic.AppName" value="fitness.flexybox.com" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" cookieless="AutoDetect" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Utils" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpellChecker" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.XtraCharts" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.XtraCharts.Web" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.XtraReports" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.XtraReports.Web" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <globalization culture="da-DK" uiCulture="da-DK" />
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="FlexyFitnessMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="FlexyFitnessMembershipProvider" type="FlexyBox.MVC.Fitness.Controllers.FlexyFitnessMembershipProvider" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <!-- IIS 6.0 & Visual Studio - Registers a module that is used to detect any new requests to the web site. Without this module mobile detection and redirection won't work.-->
    <httpModules>
      <add name="Detector" type="FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Detection.DetectorModule, FiftyOne.Foundation" />
      <add name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
      <!-- IIS 7.X - Registers 51Degrees Detector Module. Without this call to 51Degrees.core.js won't work.-->
      <remove name="Detector" />
      <add name="Detector" type="FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Detection.DetectorModule, FiftyOne.Foundation" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" name="ASPxUploadProgressHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Facebook" publicKeyToken="58cb4f2111d1e6de" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.10.0" newVersion="6.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.1.4000" newVersion="3.3.1.4000" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="51Degrees.mobi" version="3.2.3.2" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Facebook" version="6.0.18" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="jquery.mobile" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="0.1.1" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.9.0.1" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive" version="2.0.20126.16343" />
  <package id="json2" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Knockout.Mapping" version="2.3.4" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="knockout.mapping.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="0.0.2" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="knockout.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="0.0.9" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="knockoutjs" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.0.6" />
  <package id="Mvc2" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="RestSharp" version="104.4.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="System.Json" version="4.0.20126.16343" />
  <package id="System.Web.Providers" version="1.1" />
  <package id="System.Web.Providers.Core" version="1.0" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net4" />
</packages>
```

**FlexyBox.MVC.Fitness.csproj**

```
<Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.4.1.9004, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb42632606e9261f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Antlr.3.4.1.9004\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Castle.Core, Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\Lib\Castle.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.Charts.v15.1.Core, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.Printing.v15.1.Core, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.Data.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.Office.v15.1.Core, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.Docs.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.RichEdit.v15.1.Core, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.SpellChecker.v15.1.Core, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.Utils.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpellChecker.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.Web.Mvc.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v15.1.Web, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.PivotGrid.v15.1.Core, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.XtraReports.v15.1.Extensions, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.Sparkline.v15.1.Core, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.XtraReports.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.XtraReports.v15.1.Web, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.XtraPrinting.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.v15.1, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.v15.1.Extensions, Version=15.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ExceptionHandling.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\Lib\ExceptionHandling.API.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Facebook, Version=6.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Facebook.6.0.18\lib\net40-client\Facebook.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="FiftyOne.Foundation, Version=3.2.3.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e967ae578dabd98e, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\51Degrees.mobi.3.2.3.2\lib\NET40\FiftyOne.Foundation.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender">
  <HintPath>..\Lib\HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.1\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle">
  <HintPath>..\Lib\NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="RestSharp, Version=104.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\RestSharp.104.4.0\lib\net4\RestSharp.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="StructureMap, Version=2.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e60ad81abae3c223, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\Lib\StructureMap.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
<Reference Include="System.Json, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Json.4.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Abstractions" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Providers">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Web.Providers.Core.1.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Providers.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
<Reference Include="System.Web" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Routing" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
<Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
<Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
<Reference Include="WebGrease, Version=1.5.2.14234, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\lib\WebGrease.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Under which project template was it created ? If you create an empty project, using one of the MVC project templates, can you see the views inheriting from the correct namespaces?

Comment: Creating a new MVC project results in correct inheritance, but it uses the newest version of MVC, resulting in a different web.config, referenced dlls, and packages.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem myself. Turned out I had a reference to the namespace "System.Web.WebPages" in the directory web.config file, which apparently overrides System.Web.Mvc in the global web.config file.

Try commenting out the following line, in every web.config where it's found:

`<add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />`

For me, that made all the pages start referencing System.Web.Mvc instead of System.Web.WebPages.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have [Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48222) installed.

Don't forget to restart Visual Studio afterwards.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upgrade to one of the newer versions of ASP.NET due to other projects referencing older versions.

Comment: Can you update the references in the solution using a Update-Package in the Package Manager Console, at the solution level ?